# Is Kayaba Akihiko the boss of the 100th floor of New Aincrad?

Tags: sword-art-online

In the anime *Sword Art Online*, the floors from 76-100 have been untouched since Kirito beat Kayaba, but before Kirito does so, Kayaba Akihiko said, "I was meant to be the final boss at the 100th floor."

Now that there is a **New Aincrad** built in Alfheim Online.

Is it possible that Kayaba Akihiko is waiting on the 100th floor for a rematch? Or could the end boss just be another random boss for them to fight?

Comment: if you had done a little research, you might have found this [reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/swordartonline/comments/4k245l/discussion_who_is_the_100th_floor_boss_in_new/)

Comment: @Mansuro unless i missed something there's very little in that reddit thread that is of any use. at the very most they talk about the Floor 100 boss in Hollow Fragment which is set in Sword Art Online, not New Aincrad in Alfhiem Online (and also different canon). the rest either talks about the dungeon in the Town of Beginnings or guessing any character (like Klien)

Comment: @Memor-X _Well, in the Playstation game it's the hooded figure that Kayaba/Heathbar used to address all the players on Floor 1. I think it was called the <Hollow Avatar>_

It's probably just a new monster. It would be cool if it was a Heathcliff AI though.

Comment: Well we do see that Kayaba does still exist in Alfheim when he contacts Kirito after his fight with "Fairy King Oberon," so this same form might be the boss of New Aincrad.

Comment: To close voters, I think this question is answerable since we know what happened to Heathcliff. Although, since we know what happened to him, it makes this a rather bad question.

Answer (score 7):

To my understanding New Aincrad's Floor 100 has to to be revealed however the likelihood that it's Akihiko Kayaba is low.

- After Sword Art Online was cleared Kayaba did a full dive and it was reported that he was killed in the process. it can be speculated that the Full Dive was successful however there is no evidence to definitely prove that Kayaba is alive
- New Aincrad was released by Ymir, the company that now own Alfheim Online. the data from New Aincrad pre-exited on the Alfhiem Online Serves because of how ALO is a copy of SAO, however Aincrad had been altered.

> Due to the bought ALO data including copied data from the old Sword Art Online server, New Aincrad (with several changes from the original Aincrad in SAO) and Sword Skills were introduced into ALfheim Online and surviving SAO players were able to inherit their avatar data from SAO.

Source: [Ymir - Background (Second Paragraph)](http://swordartonline.wikia.com/wiki/Ymir)

- The Floors of New Aincrad are being slowly released so there is an upper limit until an update. this is evident in Sword Art Online 2 Episode 18 where Agil shows Kirito and Asuna the release notes for the next ALO update, including the introduction of the 21st-30th floors of New Aincrad. so at the moment (as of the end of Sword Art Online 2, I haven't read the Novels) no one can access Floor 100. if i was to speculate there is no data for Floor 100 (except for the outside appearance for the sake of scenery) until the update is released

Answer (score 2):

Near the end of the movie *Sword Art Online: Ordinal Scale*

> Kirito and his friends are fighting the Boss on Floor 100 of Aincrad. The Boss isn't Heathcliff, just a very strong Monster with a huge size.

Comment: it should be noted that Ordinal Scale is original and not adapted from the original Light Novels. unless there's been an announcement it's unsure if it's canon compatible

Answer (score 1):

My answer is the same with Memor-X, but for a different reason. It is next to impossible for Kayaba to be the final boss for floor 100 of New Aincrad.

1. Like Memor-X said in his answer, Kayaba is **dead, physically**. I say physically because it was shown that Kayaba is **alive as a data** after he did full dive and transferred his consciousness into the network. This was explained in the Light Novel by his former assistant, [Koujiro Rinko](http://swordartonline.wikia.com/wiki/Koujiro_Rinko). Kayaba did show up when Kirito went against Oberon at the climax of Alfheim Online, but after that, **his whereabouts is unknown**.
2. Kayaba was responsible for the death of players in the original Aincrad. He was the one who trapped everyone inside the game and made it so that the system kills anyone who died in the game. This makes him **a wanted man**. If he is physically alive, he would have been arrested and brought for trial.
3. Having Kayaba as the final boss of the 100th floor of New Aincrad would be a **bad move for the company** to make. How would people feel if, let's say Square-Enix use Hitler as the final boss for Final Fantasy? Same case with Kayaba.

So, Kayaba as the boss of the 100th floor of New Aincrad? It is next to impossible.

Comment: I agree with points 1 and 2, but 3 is speculation for the most part. It could still be possible that a "shadow," of Kayaba could be used as the boss--albeit not Kayaba himself visually to avoid press/legal issues. Again though, speculation.

Comment: Though I do agree it's near impossible.

Comment: Point 3 is based on real world. SE having Hitler as the final boss would not mean they have the real Hitler as the final boss. It would mean they have a character similar to Hitler in appearance as the final boss, which would make people upset and probably ban the game. This in turn would make their stock crash and sure as hell they would not want that. So New Aincrad having a man that is well known to be responsible for the death of thousands as the final boss? Unless the CEO & stock holders has gone nuts, they would not do that.

Comment: did Koujiro Rinko say Kayaba's full dive was successful? my impression from the end of Fairy Dance was that it's left unknown as when Kayaba appears he says he's an echo and appears to play down that he is the real Kayaba

Comment: Yes, it was a success. Kayaba successfully digitized his mind.

Comment: Kayaba's wikia page also agrees with me. http://swordartonline.wikia.com/wiki/Kayaba_Akihiko

Comment: also Atlas used Hitler as the second last Boss in Shin Megami Tensei Persona 2 Innocent Sin and Wolfienstien 3D used Hitler as a Boss. i wouldn't think using Hitler as any boss is a bad idea because in the end you kill the boss. that said i don't deny the third point Ymir did a bold move to release New Aincrad considering the emotional turmoil some players might have especially after what Rect Progress did.

Comment: @AyaseEri i was really looking for something where she shows some proof that the echo Kirito saw is the real Kayaba but like i said it was just my impression from the anime that Kayaba was playing down his survival. i havn't read the Light Novels

Answer (score -3):

All I know is that in the movie *SAO: Ordinal Scale*, Kirito and everyone else advanced to floor 100 as to beat the boss and stop all the monsters IRL. I do believe that as Kayaba Akihiko commit suicide, he wasn't on floor 100 of new Aincrad. However, when Sword Art Online was still running, he was. Although it looked like floor 100 was a little easy to beat as there weren't many people helping.

I'm pretty sure they would of all been jealous that Kirito got the floor 100's sword. Even though I am trying to stay on topic, it was said in Aincrad, in Liz's blacksmith shop, that Kirito had the best sword a monster could drop, however, Kirito gains a much better sword from floor 100. Any thoughts?

Comment: This answer was all over the place.  It's unclear as to what you're answering, or if you're just responding to it (and if you are just responding, that's not what answers are really meant for).

Comment: Hi, welcome to Anime.SE. This site is a bit different than other forums, that we're a Q&A site, not a discussion site. The first part of this answer might be a valid answer, though some references could improve it. However, looks like the second part regarding "Kirito getting the floor 100's sword" is unrelated to the topic at all, and I'm afraid it's distracting from the real topic of "the boss of the 100th floor of New Aincrad". Could you [edit] to remove the last part and add some references to the first part? Lastly, consider taking a quick [tour] to get familiar with how this site works.